# how to fix constraint problem on iphone x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have very old project its working fine till iPhone se 6 it has no constraint set but it work perfectly , when ever i am trying to use this on iPhone x it shows some white space on top and bottom but work perfect , when ever i add launch image it removes white space but shows little screen like lot of space on right side etc , is there are any way to fix this without adding constraint on all .xib file, this is very big project if add constraint on all screens it take time  so i want to find some middle way please guide me

Comment: You could calculate the position and dimensions on your own in the code pre-constraints time style

Comment: can u give me some example how to do this please

Comment: Create your view (you may already have it), set an @IBOutlet in code and connect, calculate the size and position of the view taking as reference the UIViewController's `.view.frame`, set the new `.frame` of your view.

Comment: but all these work fine without launch screen only space on top and bottom